# grails encrypt password in mysql database

Tags: mysql, grails, encryption

I am trying to encrypt password which are stored in my mysql database, the connection to the databse work well but i don't understand how to encrypt the password i tried something i saw on a tutorial but it doesn"t work here is my domain class

I am using the 2.4.4 version of grails

```
package jweb

class Clients {

    transient springSecurityService

    int id
    String name
    String password

    static constraints = {
        id()
        name()
        password()
    }
    def beforeInsert(){
        encodePassword()
    }
    def encodePassword(){
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password,null)
    }
}
```

Edit

I found a way to do it, but i think that you are right Burt, i should certainly use sprinSecurity but i am a beginner in grails and i didn't succeed to make it work so at this time i have this

```
package jweb

import java.security.MessageDigest

class Clients {

    int id
    String name
    String password
    String cart_id
    boolean admin
    static constraints = {
        id()
        name()
        password()
        cart_id nullable:true
        admin()
    }
    def beforeInsert(){
        encodePassword()
    }
    def beforeUpdate(){
        encodePassword()
    }
    def encodePassword(){
       MessageDigest md5Digest;
       byte[] digest;

       md5Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
       md5Digest.reset();
       md5Digest.update(password.getBytes());
       digest = md5Digest.digest();
       password = new BigInteger(1,digest).toString(16)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's code from the spring-security-core plugin, from a generated user class. It hashes passwords, but doesn't encrypt - if you encrypt you can decrypt, but hashes are lossy and one-way. Do you want to hash or encrypt?

Comment: I am trying to encrypt the clients password because i don't want to store raw password in my database, but i think i need to decrypt them if i want to test the password when the clients login or maybe i just have to compare the hash ?

Comment: encrypt/decrypt doesn't make any sense, if you your code know encryption key then hacker who got access to the system know it too. you could compare hashes instead

Comment: Right - it's rare to encrypt passwords. Instead, when logging in you hash the cleartext password the user entered and see if it's the same as (or equivalent to, depending on the algorithm) the hashed password in the database. You should not do this yourself though - use Spring Security, or Shiro, or another existing framework and/or plugin. Don't roll your own security.